# Clearing Image on Click (Color Visualizer With HTML and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created (with the help of a member on this website) a metal building color visualizer which can be found [here](http://metaldepotinc.com/BD.html). For some reason I can't attach the code snippets but I have a link to the full code in the comments below. 
Everything works great but there is a glitch. When I click on the colors from left to right, I have no problems. But when clicking the colors from right to left, the image layer stays above the previous image layer. Is there a way to fix this? My idea was when clicking on the color swatch, the previous layer would be cleared. I'm not sure if this would work though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do try to include some code, you can do so through the SO editor. It takes a lot more time for us to debug if we need to start inspecting your code. Also, your question wouldn't make sense anymore if the link breaks later on.

Comment: Hello, I tried multiple times but keep getting this message. "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: Looking at what is happening, you just need to remove the `active` class from the element which has it when you set the new active class.

Comment: Code here: https://pastebin.com/Zy7TKa1J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it only works left to right and not the other way is because **all your image elements are stacked on top of one another**. So when you show one image, that prevents all the other images under it from being displayed. The way you set up the html sort of prevents you from properly using a toggle for hiding divs.

The simple solution is to hide all other elements in that image group (wall group, door group, etc) before toggling. I added a few divs which group the images together, when you click on an image it grabs the parent div and then loops through hides all the non-clicked images in that image group. It then toggles the clicked image like normal.

This likely is not the best way to do this. Ideally I would redesign the html to use just use one div per group and inject the image into the div. However this should work for the structure of your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .mySlides {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;

  function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    if (n > x.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = x.length
    }
    var children = x[slideIndex - 1].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('img')
    var clickedElement = x[slideIndex - 1]
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i] != clickedElement) {
        children[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
    clickedElement.classList.toggle("active");
  }
</script>

<body>
  WALL COLOR:
  <img onclick="currentDiv(1)" src="BAG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(2)" src="BBS.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(3)" src="BCB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(4)" src="BCG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(5)" src="BHB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(6)" src="BKB.png" />
  <br> ROOF COLOR:
  <img onclick="currentDiv(7)" src="BAG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(8)" src="BBS.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(9)" src="BCB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(10)" src="BCG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(11)" src="BHB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(12)" src="BKB.png" />
  <br> TRIM COLOR:
  <img onclick="currentDiv(13)" src="BAG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(14)" src="BBS.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(15)" src="BCB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(16)" src="BCG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(17)" src="BHB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(18)" src="BKB.png" />
  <br> DOOR COLOR:
  <img onclick="currentDiv(19)" src="BAG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(20)" src="BBS.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(21)" src="BCB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(22)" src="BCG.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(23)" src="BHB.png" />
  <img onclick="currentDiv(24)" src="BKB.png" />
  <br>
  <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position: relative;">
    <div class="wall-colors">
      <img src="http://metaldepotinc.com/Canvas-Background.png" style="width:100%;position: absolute ;z-index:-1">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WAG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WBS.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WCB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WCG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WHB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/WKB.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="roof-colors">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RAG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RBS2.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RCB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RCG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RHB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/RKB.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="trim-colors">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/TAG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/TBS.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/TCB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/TCG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/THB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/TKB.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="door-colors">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DAG.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DBS.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DCB2.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DCG2.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DHB.png" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="http://metaldepotinc.com/DKB.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you!